# OpenShift HTTP to dev.markitondemand.com Blocked

Tags: java, openshift

In Openshift with java cartridge I cannot connect to this host: dev.markitondemand.com. I am using Tomcat with Java 1.7 HttpUrlConnection. The site connect is on port 80 its http. I also tried curl on openshift shell to this host and it errors out with connect error. I don't think they block OpenShift IP access but it hangs like a firewall is blocking it. I have other calls to HTTP webservices on this app and they get out fine.

Comment: So, they're probably expecting some headers that you need to mock?

Comment: @DariusX. is probably right. I ssh'ed into my OpenShift gear and I was able to curl their API without any issues http://fpaste.org/152239/16422505/